# ListBoxItem style in <ListBox.Resources> or in <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, styles

I can put a xaml `Style` for `ListBoxItem` in `<ListBox.Resources>` or in `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`. See code.
Question is: what is the difference, what should I prefer?

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

OR:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

There is an answer that I accept, but behold and think about this strange symptom:
**Either way** gives me this strange databinding warning: *Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null .... etc.*
This is a binding that is hidden somewhere in the system Aero styles, it is not mine.
Only when I use **both styles** this warning **disappears!**

Comment: Difference is that if you put in `Resources` it will apply to all `ListBoxItem` children in visual tree. So if you have nested `ListBox` it will apply to that as well as opposed to `ItemContainerStyle` which will apply only to this `ListBox`

Comment: Try setting OverridesDefaultStyle in the ItemContainerStyle ListBoxItem style to true to remove the binding error.

Comment: That property is not available in `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: I mean the ListBoxItem style in the ItemContainerStyle section

Comment: O yes, the I get an empty controltemplate, so I have to define a complete listboxitem controltemplate.

Comment: After some tries, I believe a simple controltemplate defintion gives me the best control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ItemContainerStyle` is the right way to do this because its set explicitly and so wpf will not need to look up always where the style might be. Its faster and better. That is why that property is there.

When `ItemContainerStyle` is not set WPF will seek for the style in `ListBox.Resources` or `Window.Resources` or `Application.Resources`. That is bad for performance.

Comment: That's some of assertion - `Its faster and better`. Any links supporting that assertion or data?

Comment: Well debug the source code and you will see. Once ItemContainerStyle set the flag haslocalstyle will be set to true and so the tree walker won't be user to visit nodes in logical or visual tree to find the default or implict style. Not sure if this is mentioned anywhere in msdn documentation. Probably not.

Comment: See my edit in the question for a follow-up symptom.

Comment: So you mean - `<TextBox/>` will be slower than `<TextBox Style="SomeStyle"/>` because first one will traverse till root to find style?

Comment: Yes though the effect is in milliseconds and if you had 20 resourcedictionary which might happen when you writing your own theme you will notice that listbox doesnt scroll that smooth anymore since items are added or removed to visualtree and on each change the lookup process must proceed those 20 resourcedictionaries. So in the end technically itemcontainerstyle would be best way. In the end both approaches will give you a style. However one if faster than another.

Comment: However, I still don't agree with the assertion you are making because XAML is compiled to BAML and all StaticResources are resolved at that time only (not DynamicResource though which is deffered till runtime).  Resource lookup at time of scroll, that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: StaticResources have nothing to do with lookup process finding the Style. You dont have to set Staticresouce on Style property for the style to be found. I am sorry for dissapointing you but maybe you should check again how wpf works.

Comment: I would have loved to believe that if you present some data to prove the strong assertion you make. And regarding - `You should check again how wpf works.` Sure I am doing that, thanks for showing your concern. Guess you are reading some other book for WPF which microsoft never released. I rest my case with that.

Comment: I am not reading any "other books". There is even a question in microsofts 70-511 certificate exam about look up behavior for themes. btw its my job to develop wpf controls and I have been doing my job pretty fine for past 5 years so I guess I know what I am talking about.

Comment: @dev - No hard feeling bro. All said was in heat of moment. Hope you didn't take it personally. Have a nice day..!! :)

Answer (score 6):

First is `default Style` and second is `Explicit style`.

First one will be **applied to all `ListBoxItems` found under VisualTree of parent ListBox**.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <!-- default Style -->
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ListBox>
           <ListBoxItem/> <-- Will be applied to this as well.
        </ListBox>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

whereas second one **will be applied to only `ListBoxItems` corresponding to outer ListBox**.

Second is equivalent to:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

---

If you look at the default style declared under `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` via ILSpy, you can see these two setters over there:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
```

So, when you **set that in your default style declared under resource, it overrides those setters** and hence error goes away.

But, in case you set it on style declared inline of `ItemContainerStyle` that error won't go away since it still refer to the default style. In case you don't want to basedOn default style set `BasedOn` attribute to `x:Null`.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{x:Null}"/>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: See my edit in the question for a follow-up symptom.

Comment: Where is that binding define? Can you post that as well.

Comment: Added: it is a system binding hidden in a system style somewhere. It shows up using Wpf Inspector. My own setter (see question) tries to get rid of it, which only succeeds when I do it in both places.

Comment: @Gerard - Added the reason for those binding errors in my question.

Comment: When I set that in my style, the errors do **not** go away, only when I set them on both places (see question)!

Comment: besides it should find the ancestor and not complain.

Comment: @Gerard - May be i was not clear enough. I meant if you declare it under resource only and set both `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` error will go away. But in case you set it for `ItemContainerStyle`, it won't go away because that style is still based on default style. You have to set `BasedOn` to `x:Null` to get away with that error.

Comment: Regarding `besides it should find the ancestor and not complain.` - I agree with you on this. May be when style is looked upon for listBoxItem, it's still not added as visual child of ListBox. That's too a wild guess, I was too amazed to see that. Have a nice day..!! :)

Comment: thanks for thinking along, but the suggestion doesn't work in my code.

Comment: OK no issues. I tried this at my end and worked perfectly for me though..!!